# Java - Using an object inside an object

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I am working on a project ( I had a problem yesterday and so many people helped me!) so I decided to ask for help again.

My code has 3 classes. ProjectMain,Students,Classroom. I created an array of Classroom objects. Right now I have 3 Classroom objects. But I have to assign student objects to these Classroom objects. For example : classarray[0] is an object from Classroom class and studentobject.get(0) , studentobject.get(1) ... will be students objects inside classarray[0] object. But I have failed on this while coding. Here are my classes :

```
  public class Classroom
{

    private String classname;
    private String word[] = null;
    protected ArrayList<Students> studentobject = new ArrayList<Students>(10);

    public String[] getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String[] word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public ArrayList<Students> getStudentobject()
    {
        return studentobject;
    }

    public void setStudentobject(ArrayList<Students> studentobject)
    {
        this.studentobject = studentobject;
    }

    public String getClassname()
    {
        return classname;
    }

    public void setClassname(String classname)
    {
        this.classname = classname;
    }

    public void classroomreader(String filename)
    {
        // This method gets the name of Classroom
        File text = new File("C:/Users/Lab/Desktop/classlists/" + filename
                + ".txt");
        Scanner scan;
        try
        {

            scan = new Scanner(text);
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            word = line.split("\t");
            line = scan.nextLine();
            word = line.split("\t");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

This is my student class :

```
public class Students extends Classroom
{

    private String name,id;
    private int age;




    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
```

And my main class :

```
public class ProjectMain
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Classroom[] classarray = new Classroom[3];


        //I got 3 Classroom objects here
        classarray[0]=new Classroom();
        classarray[1]=new Classroom();
        classarray[2]=new Classroom();

        classarray[0].classroomreader("class1"); 

        classarray[0].studentobject.get(0).setName(classarray[0].getWord()[1]);
//The problem is in here. When my code comes to the line above, 
// at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) error comes out. 
// I tried to get first object in studentobject Arraylist, and tried to set it's name 
// to the variable which my text reader reads.
```

How can I write what I have in my mind?

Comment: studentobject.get() doesn't reference anything.  You have a method called getstudentobject()

Comment: You have `Students extends Classroom` - I don't think a "students" is a kind of a "classroom".

Comment: I'd read up on `Is-a` (extends) `Has-a` (references) relationship and inheritance. It helps to say it out loud. Does "Student Is-a Classroom" make sense? should it not be "Classroom Has-a Student"?

Comment: You never create any instance of Students... as classarray[0].studentobject is empty, trying to get it's first instance it fails...

Answer (score 0):

Your classroomreader method reads the file but don't do much of it... maybe you want to create some instance of Students within it.

```
        scan = new Scanner(text);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        word = line.split("\t"); // won't be used
        line = scan.nextLine();
        word = line.split("\t"); // erased here
```

There you only have the last line (split) of the file in word attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When creating `Classroom` instance `studentobject` list is created empty and it stays that way so you can't access first (or any) object in it.

To populate your list you may add to `Classroom` method like this:

```
public void addStudent(Student s)
{
    studentobject.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

classroom contains the following field declaration

```
String word[] = null;
```

the main class, incl the classroomreader does not set a value to this field. Yet you are going to invoke

```
classarray[0].getWord()[1]
```

which then must fail.

tip: don't use expressions like this, which can be found in your main class  (at least not in early stages of development, or learning)

```
classarray[0].studentobject.get(0).setName(classarray[0].getWord()[1]);
```

resolve into variables and several steps. Compilers are smart enough to produce the same code if the context is not disturbed, ie the long expression is resolved into a single block.
Never forget that the purpose of programming languages is to make programs readable for humans. :)  Code with abbreviations or "tricks" simply shows some philodoxical attitude (imho)